# ¿Por qué me agrega un dato dos veces?

Tags: python, poo

Estoy empezando un programa de banco, el problema es que cuando me ingresan 2 o mas usuarios así el dni de ellos se repita me los agrega.

Creo que el error esta en que las listas siempre se inician vacías en la funcion `agregar_clientes()`. No he podido lograr corregir este error, no utilizo base de datos porque aun no he llegado a ese tema

```
class Cliente():
    def __init__(self,opcion):
        self.opcion=opcion

    def agregar_cliente(self):
        usuarios=[]     #Lista para almacenar los usuarios
        lista_dni=[]    #Lista para comparar si ya hay un usuario con el mismo DNI

        nombre=str(input("\nDigite el nombre del usuario: "))
        apellido=str(input("Digite el apellido del usuario"))
        dni=int(input("Digite el DNI del usuario: "))


        if len(lista_dni)==0: #Si la lista de DNI esta vacia me agregue el usuario sin comparar nada
            usuarios.append([nombre,apellido,lista_dni])
            lista_dni.append(dni) #Agrego el dni a la lista, para cuando ingresen otro usuario comparar si el dni se repite
            print("Usuario agregado")

        elif len(lista_dni)>0: #Si la lista de DNI tiene elementos, que me compare el dni que ingresaron con los dni que hay en la lista
            for a in range(len(lista_dni)):

                if lista_dni[a]==dni: #Si al recorrer la lista de DNI, un elemento coincide con el dni nuevo no me agregue el usuario
                    print("Ya hay un usuario con este DNI")
                else:
                    usuarios.append([nombre,apellido,dni]) #De lo contrario agreguemelo
                    print("Usuario agregado")
                    print(usuarios)

        return usuarios,lista_dni,usuarios


def main():

    print("\n****   BIENVENIDO AL BANCO   ****")

    while(True):
        try:
            print("""\nDigite una opcion: 
\n1) Agregar usuario
2) Visualizar usuario
3) Eliminar usuario
4) Salir""")

            opcion=int(input("\nDigite una opcion: "))

            if opcion==1:
                objeto=Cliente(opcion)
                objeto.agregar_cliente()


        except ValueError:
            print("\nopcion incorrecta, intentelo nuevamente")


if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: no queda claro el error. ¿Podrías mostrar un ejemplo de entrada y cómo se guarda, así como cómo lo querrías guardar?

Comment: Por otra parte, llevas bastantes preguntas ya: considera leer [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), así como mostrar títulos de preguntas más descriptivos y poner solamente el código necesario para que se te pueda ayudar mejor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero debes tener en cuenta el ámbito de las variables para que puedas determinar su ciclo de vida.

Segundo puedes hacer uso del condicional `if` para comprobar si existe o no el `dni` en la `lista_dni`

Por ultimo, como ves dentro del condicional uso el `return` para "terminar" con la función cuando la repuesta sea `True` y en caso de que la condición obtenga `False` imprime el mensaje de dni existente y termina la función.

```
class Cliente():
    def __init__(self,opcion):
        self.opcion=opcion

    def agregar_cliente(self, usuarios, lista_dni):

        nombre=str(input("\nDigite el nombre del usuario: "))
        apellido=str(input("Digite el apellido del usuario: "))
        dni=int(input("Digite el DNI del usuario: "))

        if not dni in lista_dni:
          usuarios.append([nombre,apellido,lista_dni])
          lista_dni.append(dni)
          print("Usuario agregado")
          return usuarios, lista_dni

        print("Ya hay un usuario con este DNI")


def main():
    usuarios=[]     #Lista para almacenar los usuarios
    lista_dni=[]    #Lista para comparar si ya hay un usuario con el mismo DNI

    print("\n****   BIENVENIDO AL BANCO   ****")

    while(True):
        try:
            print("""\nDigite una opcion: 
                     \n1) Agregar usuario
                     2) Visualizar usuario
                     3) Eliminar usuario
                     4) Salir""")

            opcion=int(input("\nDigite una opcion: "))

            if opcion==1:
                objeto=Cliente(opcion)
                objeto.agregar_cliente(usuarios, lista_dni)


        except ValueError:
            print("\nopcion incorrecta, intentelo nuevamente")


if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias me ayudaste bastante